# How to avoid duplication in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
SELECT title, retail, (SELECT AVG(retail)
                 FROM   books) 
FROM   books
WHERE  retail < (SELECT AVG(retail)
                 FROM   books)
```

Is there a way to shorten one of (SELECT AVG(retail)
                 FROM   books) to an alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT title, retail, AVG(retail) OVER() avg_retail
    FROM   books
    )
WHERE  retail < avg_retail
```

or using a WITH:

```
WITH dat AS
(
    SELECT title, retail, AVG(retail) OVER() avg_retail
    FROM   books
)
SELECT *
  FROM dat
 WHERE  retail < avg_retail
```

Comment: I'm trying to find an explanation of what over() does, here http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/search?word=over&tab_id=15&partno=, do you have a direct link or maybe an explanation?

Comment: Check this: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm#i1006928

Answer (score 2):

you could refactor with the `WITH` clause, maybe like this:

```
With avg_retail as
    (SELECT AVG(retail) the_avg
    FROM   books) 
SELECT title, retail, avg_retail.the_avg
from books, avg_retail
where books.retail < avg_retail.the_avg;
```